# Emulate Crash Recovery in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, crash

Does anybody know if IE has an API for emulating the browser's automated crash recovery feature (ACR)?

I want to be able to manually save the browser session to file (ACR writes session data to compound file binary format) and restore that session using what was saved.

Answer (score 0):

What information do you want to store?  If you want window size/position/tab states, including history for each tab, I don't know (though I can see reasons not to expose that, from a security/malware-protection point of view).

If you want to store page state locally, there are lots of different options - though the one you're probably most interested in is [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage). (There's an equivalent, though more ceremonious, API for IE as well.)